# Javascript: Creating an analog clock with threejs using rotate

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, radians

I have an analog clock in my scene that I would like to update with the current time. Right now I can make the clock keep time by calculating the rotation of each hand at 1 second intervals, but I am seeing some weird results for the minute and hour hands.

```
hourHand = scene.getObjectByName('Box001');
minuteHand = scene.getObjectByName('Box002');
secondHand = scene.getObjectByName('Cylinder002');

var d = new Date();

var mins = d.getMinutes();
var secs = d.getSeconds();
var hours = d.getHours();

minuteHand.rotateY((-mins / 60) * (2 * Math.PI));
secondHand.rotateY(((mins /60) + (-secs / 3600)) * (2 * Math.PI));
hourHand.rotateY(((-hours / 12) + (mins / 720)) * (2 * Math.PI));


setInterval(function(){
    minuteHand.rotateY((2 * Math.PI) / -3600);
    secondHand.rotateY((2 * Math.PI) / -60);
    hourHand.rotateY((2 * Math.PI) / (-3600 * 12));
},1000);
```

The problems that I am having are:

- If the time is 4:30, the hour hand is at 4 when it should be between the 4 and the 5, same problem with the minute hand
- I am not sure if the math I am using is correct because I am seeing some odd problems over time that I cannot pin down.

Is there a more exact way to do this?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do a fiddle because of the cross domain issues and some privacy concerns for the model I am using. I will provide any information I can though.

Comment: I made a fiddle that shows the update. 
https://jsfiddle.net/DezOnlyOne/ag5gds3f/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no guarantee that your interval actually fires every 1000ms, so of course over time there will accumulate error, because you have no way of "catching up" with previous delays.

I would recommend to you to base the hand rotation on a function that uses the current time as input. That way it doesn't matter *when* your interval / trigger / callback executes, but whenever it does it will show the correct result.

The math isn't too complicated, a clock has obviously 360 degrees, so from the top of my head that would mean

`(Date.now()/1000)%60 * 6` would be your secondHand rotation in degrees (assuming 0° is top), likewise

`(Date.now()/60000)%60 * 6` should be the minute rotation and

<s>`(Date.now()/3600000)%24 * 15` your hourHand.</s>
**Update** silly me, set up this formula for a 24h rotation. You'd want this to be 12h for a *normal* clock, so this would become:

`(Date.now()/3600000)%12 * 30`

take those calculations with a grain of salt, didn't take the time to verify this.

Comment: The second and minute hands are great. The hour hand is off. I am looking into that calculation right now. Thanks for your help. You got me a lot closer.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, of course it's wrong. Wasn't thinking too long about this and as you can see, calculated your hour hand based on a 24 hour rotation. While a designer might think this is a fancy idea, I guess you'd rather want 12 hours per rotation. Updating my answer now.

Comment: I have updated my function with your advice. Only the hour hand is still off. I understand the math that is used, and it makes sense. Maybe the getTime is returning the wrong value? Do I need to set the new Date to my time zone? Here is a fiddle I made. 
https://jsfiddle.net/DezOnlyOne/ag5gds3f/1/

Comment: @DezOnlyOne yes, the returned time will be in UTC timezone. I don't think you can configure it

Comment: @DezOnlyOne for a more granular functionality I would go for a library like moment.js, they even have an analog clock example on their start page which you can inspect in core-home.js
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: thanks for your help. using moment.js I got a clock that really works well in my scene and is always correct. I offset the hour hand by 90 degrees and now it is correct